# How change the videos max of page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have one website here that contains videos to see, like youtube, and the videos are divided in pages, and in the source of this page I got this part of the source:

```
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="vid_count">
<input type="hidden" value="422" id="vid_max">
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="vids_per_page">
```

The site contains 422 videos with 36 pages, 12 videos per page

I need to show all videos in only one page...

I've already tried

```
document.getElementById("vids_per_page").setAttribute("value", "500");
```

but this doesn't work...

How can I do it? (via greasemonkey)

any additional info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just about changing values, this will do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("vids_per_page").value = document.getElementById("vid_max").value;
```

I don't know what `vid_count` means, so you might also need to do this:

```
document.getElementById("vids_per_page").value = document.getElementById("vid_max").value;
```

Are you sure `vid_count` isn't 422? Just to be sure, try this:

```
document.getElementById("vids_per_page").value = "422";
```

Comment: damn, didn't worked... and yes, the count is 12.. don't know why